# NUC DN2820FYKH ubuntu 14.04 UEFI

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have updated my BIOS to the latest version yesterday and since then the machine can't find bootable drive.

I can boot using EFI console, but it doesn't play ball otherwise! I tried boot-repair but that didn't fix the problem in the BIOS there are can see entries for the UEFI but when you select it it doesn't boot.

just to clarify this machine has only UBUNTU 14.04 in LVM partition... no Windows

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you read up a bit on how EFI works, since your question reveals a number of common misunderstandings, largely caused by applying BIOS assumptions to the EFI world. Adam Williamson posted a useful [blog post](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) on this subject, so that's a good start. The [introduction to my page on EFI boot loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) is another site that can be a useful starting point.

The most critical point to understand is that under EFI, disks are not bootable in the same sense that they are under BIOS. EFI boot loaders are stored as files on a FAT partition known as the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) A single ESP can house any number of boot loaders. The computer decides which boot loader to use based on its own boot manager's entries, which are stored in NVRAM. You can manipulate those entries in any number of ways, such as by using the `bcfg` command in an EFI shell or the `efibootmgr` utility in Linux. The better EFIs also provide a user interface so that you can make changes from their setup tools.

Chances are your firmware update erased or re-ordered your NVRAM entries. Thus, you may need to re-create a working entry or at least change the boot order. See [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html#register) or [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#efibootmgr) for some basic information on how to do this with `efibootmgr`. In theory, the Boot Repair program you've tried should be able to do this; but it sometimes doesn't work. Also, Boot Repair *must* be run *from an EFI-mode boot* in order to do this properly. This is one of the hurdles that can be difficult to overcome, since many users accidentally boot in BIOS mode rather than in EFI mode.

My [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) can be helpful because it works *only* in EFI mode. If you download the USB flash drive or CD-R image and boot with it, you'll be guaranteed of booting rEFInd in EFI mode (or not at all). It should then detect your Linux installation -- but since you use LVM, you may need to either boot via the GRUB option or hit F2 or Insert twice and enter a correct `root=` option to boot a Linux kernel directly. Once you've booted Linux, you can use `efibootmgr` to re-enable GRUB or you can install the Debian-package version of rEFInd to use it from your hard disk.